# I added a scroll bar to my python table but it does not work well

Tags: python, tkinter

If I remove the code about the scroll bar, the table is fine.
But when I try to add this bar, my table shrinks and I can't see the scroll bar.

Here is my code (I have no errors):

```
from tkinter import *

fen = Tk()
fen.geometry('1500x800')
fen.grid()

tableau1 = Frame(fen, width=1100, height=700,)
tableau1.config(background="#45B39D")
tableau1.grid_propagate(0)

tableau1.place(x=10, y=50)


data = [["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrf","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfrf","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"]]


class tableau:
    def __init__(self, tableau1):

        h = Scrollbar(tableau1, orient='horizontal')
        h.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        v = Scrollbar(tableau1)
        v.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):

                self.e = Text(tableau1, width=10, height=1.2, fg='blue',font=('Arial',16), xscrollcommand=h.set, yscrollcommand=v.set)
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, data[i][j])
                self.e.config(state="disabled")

        h.config(command=self.e.xview)
        v.config(command=self.e.yview)


total_rows = len(data)
total_columns = len(data[0])

tableau(tableau1)

fen.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for help me!

Answer (score 0):

You should try and take a look at this video. This could help point you into the right direction. There are vertical and horizontal portions for the scroll bar as well.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT8hV6rH4Gk